# Canvas not refreshing very well in Chromium

Tags: javascript, canvas, chromium

I'm working on a project with HTML5's canvas. When refreshing a site that on load generates a canvas drawing, sometimes the page keeps in blank, sometimes it draws as intended. On Firefox works all the time.

Any suggestion about this issue and how to avoid it?

Thanks!

Comment: Way too vague to know. How about posting some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known Bug with Chromes Hardware Acceleration, maybe you should get a newer build, or disable the acceleration. I've encountered this numerous (read: endless) times over the last few month when testing out HWA.

I don't have a specific but on hand for this, partly because you didn't provide any further information and partly because Google Codes Bugtracker is crap:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=canvas+accelerated&sort=-modified&colspec=ID+Stars+Pri+Area+Feature+Type+Status+Summary+Modified+Owner+Mstone+OS&x=mstone&y=area&cells=tiles

Good luck finding something there.
*Hint: The search function is useless.*

Comment: Started using stable Chrome for linux and renders fine. Thanks.